# Determine all the values of $1^{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't seem to understand how to solve this. I mean, if we weren't dealing with complex numbers, then I suppose it is clearly 1, but I don't know how to approach this. Apparently the answer is $\cos(2\sqrt{2} k \pi) + i\sin (2 \sqrt{2} k \pi)$, but I don't know how to go through with this. Do I begin with setting it to $e^{\sqrt{2}ln(1)}$? Even then, $ln(1) = 0$, and $e^\sqrt{2}$ is just that... I'm not sure how to go about this.

In short, how do I go from $1^{\sqrt{2}}$ to $\cos(2\sqrt{2} k \pi) + i\sin (2 \sqrt{2} k \pi)$?

Comment: I see an answer here, but what is the question?

Comment: The question is how to get from $1^{\sqrt{2}}$ to the answer shown.

Comment: $\ln(1) = 0$ for the principal branch of the logarithm. But for other choices of branch cut you get $\ln(1) = 2\pi i k$ for $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Solve $x^{1/\sqrt{2}}=1\;(=e^{2i k\pi})$

Comment: How do I know all of my branches? How could I see this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Recall that $e^{x+iy}$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$. What complex values $z$ give $e^z=1$?

Expanding the hint: We start with $e^{\sqrt{2}\log(1)}$. Solving the above equation, we see that $e^{z}$ is one at precisely $2\pi ik$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $\log(1)=\{2\pi i k|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Plugging in, we have the set $e^{2\sqrt{2}\pi i k}$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Expanding according to the above, we have $e^{2\sqrt{2}\pi i k}=\cos(2\sqrt{2}\pi k)+i\sin(2\sqrt{2}\pi k)$ and we arrive at the answer.

The punchline here is that $\log(z)$ is still the inverse of $e^z$, but $e^z$ is no longer 1-1 and therefore $\log(z)$ can only be a local inverse, and there's some choice involved in which branch to pick.

Comment: Either the number is purely imaginary, or x = 1. Right?

Comment: $x\neq 1$. Solve the equation! What value of $x,y$ can you plug in to get 1?

Comment: Whoops, you're right, I didn't see that. x clearly has to be 0, and then we're left with figuring out when cos(y) = 1, and sin(y) = 0. This happens at $0, \pi, 2\pi, etc.$

Comment: Though... the answer doesn't make sense to me. $cos(2\sqrt{2}k\pi)$ does not equate to 1.

Comment: I just came back to this one, and I'm wondering: Why are you solving $e^z = 0$ and not $e^z = 1$?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I'm solving $e^{z}=1$. $e^z=0$ has no solutions.

Comment: Okay, so I understand that when solving $\cos(y) + i\sin(y)$ we need $\cos(y)$ to be 1, and $\sin(y)$ to be 0. We know x = 0 for the sake of $e^x = 1$, but why do you get $2 \pi i k$ and not $2 \pi k$ for $\cos(y) + i\sin(y)$ (I assume that is what you're solving)? And then finally, why does that particularly equate to log(1)? Apologies for what seem like trivial questions, I just really want to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: That's fine, questions is how we learn! For the part dealing with $\cos(y)+i\sin(y)=1$, I get $y=2\pi k$, which means the complex number I get which solves $e^{x+iy}=1$ is $x+iy=2\pi i k$. For the second question, recall what the definition of $\log$ is: if $a=e^b$, then $b=\log a$.

Comment: Aha! I see now. Yes, it must be $2 \pi i k$ because it is the imaginary part of the number. Alright, then we know that $e^{x + iy} = 1$, hence, $x + iy = 2 \pi i k = \log(1)$. $\log(1)$ is obtained by the fact that $log(e^{x+iy}) = log(1)$. From this, we know that $log(1) = 2 \pi i k$, and because $1^{\sqrt{2}} = e^{\sqrt{2}\log(1)}$, we have $e^{\sqrt{2}2 \pi i k} = \cos(2\sqrt{2} \pi k) + i \sin(2 \sqrt{2} \pi k)$. I believe that is right.

Answer (score 1):

$e^0 = 1$. However, remember that $e^{2\pi ki}$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is also $1$. Therefore, you can rewrite $1^{\sqrt{2}}$ as $e^{{(2\pi ki)}^{\sqrt{2}}}$, and simplify using exponent laws to $e^{2\sqrt{2}\pi ki}$. From there, use Euler's identity.